# navigation transform information problem

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d-ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I try to run the navigation stack with a real robot (move_base + gmapping).
My problem is that when I launch my launch file which is supposed to run the move_base node and the slam_gmapping node (and load my YAML configuration files), I get completely randomly warnings which disturb the behaviour of my robot.

When I send no goal, I get this warning randomly:

```
Costmap2DROS transform timeout ... could not get robot pose, cancelling pose reconfiguration
```

And when I send a goal, I get this warning randomly:

```
Unable to get starting pose of robot, unable to create global plan
```

When the first warning appear, the robot begins to get an hesitating behaviour with very slow speeds.
I didn't find anywhere a real solution to this problem.
If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful,
lfr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238803/navigation-transform-information-problem/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-07-05**:
Could you post your launch file?

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-07-06**:
Thanks for answering me. The launch files are correct. I found the problem is the communication between the robot and my computer. There are some packets which are loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I give this answer because it is possible that someone else have the same problem.

I found that the problem is with the communication between the robot and my computer.
Indeed, some packets are loss (I saw that in trying to ping the robot). And each time I lose a packet, this is exactly when the second warning appear.
Moreover, sometimes, the delay in communication exceeds my transform_tolerance (I saw that with the ping too) and this is when the first warning appear.

The only solution I can see is to improve the communication way.

I hope it can help someone to find the problem,
lfr

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0